# Completeness and norm spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I'm struggling with the proof of the following question:

Let (R^p,∥.∥) be a normed space. Prove that R^p is complete if and only if the set (S,∥.∥) is
complete, where S = {x ̄ ∈ R^p : ∥x ̄∥ = 1}.

If anyone is willing to provide me with the proof I would really appreciate it.

Kind regards 
Layla

Comment: Is $R$ supposed to be $\Bbb R$, the real numbers? In which case, you are really saying let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on the space $\Bbb R$ (there are normed vectors spaces on different fields). If you didn't mean that, then it would require whatever field $R$ is to be complete itself.

Comment: As for "providing you with a proof", you will find that is not how this site works. We will gladly help you get past problems you are having in finding answers to your homework, but doing your homework for you is a different matter.